# How does Rust implement array indexing?

Tags: arrays, rust, indices, mutability

I'm learning about substructural type systems and Rust is a good example of that.

An array is mutable in Rust and it can be accessed many times rather than only once. What is the difference between "value reads", "reference reads" and "mutable reference reads"? I wrote a program as below but I got some errors.

```
fn main() {
    let xs: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    println!("first element of the array: {}", xs[1]);
    println!("first element of the array: {}", &xs[1]);
    println!("first element of the array: {}", &mut xs[1]);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable indexed content `xs[..]` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:53
  |
2 |     let xs: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  |         -- consider changing this to `mut xs`
...
5 |     println!("first element of the array: {}", &mut xs[1]);
  |                                                     ^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow immutable field
```

Comment: I don't think `Array`s are mutable by default; hence your error.

Comment: If you're familiar with C++... `value reads` maps to `return-by-value` semantics, `reference reads` maps to const-correct `return-by-reference` semantics, and `mutable reference reads` is a bad idea in most cases and simply refers to `return-by-reference` semantics.

Answer (score 6):

`xs` is **not** mutable; in order to make it mutable its binding must contain the `mut` keyword:

```
let mut xs: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

When you add it, your code will work as expected. I recommend [the relevant section in The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/variable-bindings.html#mutability).

Indexing in Rust is an operation provided by the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) traits and, as stated in the docs, it's syntax sugar for `*container.index(index)` and `*container.index_mut(index)`, which means that it provides direct access (not just a reference) to the indexed element. The differences between the 3 operations you listed can be better seen with `assert_eq` comparisons:

```
fn main() {
    let mut xs: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    assert_eq!(xs[1], 2); // directly access the element at index 1
    assert_eq!(&xs[1], &2); // obtain a reference to the element at index 1
    assert_eq!(&mut xs[1], &mut 2); // obtain a mutable reference to the element at index 1

    let mut ys: [String; 2] = [String::from("abc"), String::from("def")];

    assert_eq!(ys[1], String::from("def"));
    assert_eq!(&ys[1], &"def");
    assert_eq!(&mut ys[1], &mut "def");
}
```

Comment: You didn't really answer OP's question(s): *How does Rust implement array read function?* and *What is the difference between "value reads", "reference reads" and "mutable reference reads"?*

Comment: I've changed the code and turned array `xs` into a mutable one but I still don't know what is the difference between those three ways of array reading. Could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit I expanded the answer a little bit; I think it's clearer now.